# Base on land cover data to get plant functional types(PFT) by using GEE, but get something wrong

Tags: google-earth-engine, raster-calculator, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-cover

By using .reduceresolution() and ee.Reducer.mean() to reduce resolution from 10m to 10000m.But the result looks like taking the most distributed elements in the area and assigning them to new pixels.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([37.4824, 9.3274,38.5396, 8.3559]);
var ECMWF = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY").first())
            .select('dewpoint_temperature_2m')
Map.setCenter(38.5396, 8.3559, 12);
var ECMWFProjection = ECMWF.projection();
print('ECMWF projection:', ECMWFProjection);//projection: EPSG:4326
var ECMWFProjection = ECMWFProjection.atScale(10000)

var startDate = '2017-01-01';
var endDate = '2018-01-01';
var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
            .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
            .filterBounds(geometry);
var classification = dw.select('label');
var dwComposite = classification.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode());
var tree = ee.List([1])
var other = ee.List([0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
var from_list=ee.List([tree,other]).flatten();
var to_list = ee.List([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
var TREE_mask=dwComposite.remap(from_list,to_list);

var dwVisParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: [
    '#419BDF', '#397D49', '#88B053', '#7A87C6', '#E49635', '#DFC35A',
    '#C4281B', '#A59B8F', '#B39FE1'
  ]
};
Map.addLayer(TREE_mask.clip(geometry),{}, 'TREE_mask');

var TREE_maskMean = TREE_mask
    .reproject({
      crs: ECMWFProjection
    })
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      bestEffort:true,
      maxPixels: 4096
    });
print(TREE_maskMean)
Map.addLayer(TREE_maskMean.clip(geometry),dwVisParams, 'TREE_maskMean');
```

here is the code link
https://code.earthengine.google.com/9a36fb030d5617ce48674ad436e2d0f3?accept_repo=users%2FCYRshare%2FLDNcode

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.